# Aligning elements in Bootstrap navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a Bootstrap 4 navbar where I cannot align the center elements on all devices (or any for that matter). Currently, there is an image on the left of the navbar and I am currently using padding to push the rest over but this is an ugly hack at best.

What I think needs to be done is the navbar needs to stretch all the way across the top of the page, instead of only to the image. That way I can align the elements to the center using something like a `text-justify` class.

What is the best way to align this?

**HTML**:

```
<!--Site header-->
<header class="site-header" id="top-bar">
    <!-- Navbar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top ml-auto">
        <div class="container col-md-12">

            <!-- Image on the left of the navbar -->
            <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto" style="padding: 0 100 0 20;">
                <a href="{% url 'landing' %}">
                    <img id="header-img" src="{% static '/bg/WEBSITE-LOGO.png' %}"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <button aria-controls="navbarToggle"
                    aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation"
                    class="navbar-toggler"
                    data-target="#navbarToggle"
                    data-toggle="collapse"
                    type="button">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <!-- Links I want aligned to center of navbar -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
                <div class="navbar-nav m-auto">
                    <div class="header-icon-container d-xs-none">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link d-xs-none" href="{% url 'overview' %}" id="overview">
                            <i class="fas fa-home fa-2x"></i>
                            <span>Home</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="header-icon-container">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#" id="drills">
                            <i class="fas fa-dumbbell fa-2x"></i>
                            <span>Drills</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- Navbar Right Side - more links -->
                <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div class="btn-group text-right">
                        <button class="account-dropdown"
                                data-toggle="dropdown"
                                type="button">
                            <img class="account-header-img" src="{{ user.image.url }}">
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li>
                                <form action="{% url 'overview' %}"
                                      class="small-form"
                                      method="get">
                                    <input class="btn btn-link link-white"
                                           type="submit"
                                           value="Test stats">
                                </form>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <form action="{% url 'categories' %}"
                                      class="small-form"
                                      method="get">
                                    <input class="btn btn-link link-white"
                                           type="submit"
                                           value="Categories">
                                </form>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <form action="{% url 'profile' %}"
                                      class="small-form"
                                      method="get">
                                    <input class="btn btn-link link-white"
                                           type="submit"
                                           value="Update profile">
                                </form>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <form action="{% url 'logout' %}"
                                      class="small-form"
                                      method="get">
                                    <input class="btn btn-link link-white"
                                           type="submit"
                                           value="Logout">
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% else %}
                    <a class="nav-item nav-link ml-auto" href="{% url 'login' %}">
                        <i class="fas fa-sign-in fa-2x"></i>
                        <span>Sign in</span>
                    </a>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: can you explain better please, you need the navbar to fill the entire viewport row ?

Comment: I want the image on the left of the navbar to always be visible. The links on the middle and right of the navbar are collapsible and I want them aligned to the center and right of the navbar respectively.

Comment: You can see that the I have added classes `mr-auto` `m-auto` and `ml-auto` to each one to push it over for now but this isn't the right way to do this I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: 
Make your navbar 100% with, create a mobile and a desktop cas (d-none d-md-block) Remove the toggle div and you should have 3 div with content insider your nav. Make it display: flex with justify-content: space-around. => 1 div (logo) is left , 2 div (links) center, 3 div (forms) right

Option 2: 
log + wrapper div wich takes the rest of the space + 2 more divs each 50% and make them text-align: center, text-align: right (poor solution)

Option 3: Navbar 100%, position relative. Img position: absolute; left: 0;, ...

I'd go for solution No.1